# Update Repeat event to one time event in google calendar - Not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar, google-calendar-api

I remove the RRULE field to update repeat event to one time event android google calendar programmatically

Inserting values - eventTimezone=en_IN description=null title=Repeat without until allDay=0 dtend=1602934200000 dtstart=1602932400000 calendar_id=3 eventLocation=null rrule=FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SU,SA;UNTIL=20201020T235959Z

Updating values - eventTimezone=en_IN description=null title=Repeat without until allDay=0 dtend=1602934200000 dtstart=1602932400000 calendar_id=3 eventLocation=null rrule=

Comment: How do you cregte and update events so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You cannot just remove the RRULE when updating a recurrent event, you need to replace it instead.

For example, if you want the event to take place only once - modify

`RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=28;UNTIL=20210131T235959Z`

to

`RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY=27;COUNT=1`

This modificaiton you can perform with [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch()) or [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update).

Comment: Do you have any idea about when tappin number in message app it shows call, message, copy and past option. Can we implement this thing into our app?

Comment: I am sorry, I ddo not work with mobile apps.

Comment: Ok thanks. No problem